# Erroneous "file not found" error for libmsodbcsql.17.dylib on macOS

Tags: python, sql-server, odbc

After following Microsoft's [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver15) for installing ODBC for SQL Server on macOS, I get an error when I try to connect via `pyodbc`:

```
Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/msodbcsql17/17.7.2.1/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

yet, the file clearly exists:

```
❯ ls -al /opt/homebrew/Cellar/msodbcsql17/17.7.2.1/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib 
-r--r--r--  1 cfonnesbeck  admin  1837940 Apr 28 15:23 /opt/homebrew/Cellar/msodbcsql17/17.7.2.1/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib
```

moreover, my `odbcinst.ini` file is specified correctly:

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib
UsageCount=1
```

where the /usr/local/lib driver is a simlink:

```
ls -al /usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  staff  67 Apr 28 14:22 /usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib -> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/msodbcsql17/17.7.2.1/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib
```

I've found similar issues on SO, which all suggest re-installing various components, but this is a clean install, and re-installation does nothing. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: did you happen to get this resolved? I'm experiencing this issue too